# I want to add a picklist field using the metadata.service code, but it doesn't work

Tags: apex

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

List<MetadataService.CustomField> customFieldList = new List<MetadataService.CustomField>();
MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestPicklistField__c';
customField.label = 'TestPicklistField';
customField.type_x = 'Picklist';

MetadataService.ValueSet vs = new MetadataService.ValueSet();
MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition vd = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

List<MetadataService.CustomValue> customValues = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
MetadataService.CustomValue cv1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
cv1.label = 'One';
cv1.fullName = 'One';
cv1.isActive = true;
cv1.default_x = false;
customValues.add(cv1);

vd.value = customValues;
vd.sorted = true;

vs.valueSetDefinition = vd;

// Use valueSet instead of Picklist
customField.valueSet  = vs;

customFieldList.add(customField);
MetadataService.SaveResult[] saveResults = service.createMetadata(customFieldList);
```

The above code is not working error looks like this

System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unable to find apex schema info

Comment: Does [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/239936/metadata-api-error-while-reading-picklist-web-service-callout-failed-unable-to) answer the question?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  This is the open-source Metadata API from Certinia.  Have you checked the [documentation](https://github.com/certinia/apex-mdapi/tree/master)?  There are multiple issues that mention this error.